# Enforcing 2FA with MS Graph module instead of Azure AD module

Tags: powershell, authentication, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I have unattended scripts for creating new MS 365 users which currently do the following:

```
$AuthObject = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Online.Administration.StrongAuthenticationRequirement
$AuthObject.RelyingParty = '*'
$AuthObject.State = 'Enabled'
$AuthObjectArray = @($AuthObject)
Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $Email -StrongAuthenticationRequirements $AuthObjectArray
```

This enables 2FA on the account.

I want to migrate away from the Azure AD module (being deprecated) to MS Graph, how do I achieve the same thing with 'Update-MgUser', 'Update-MgUserSetting' or 'New-MgUser'?

Comment: There is a lot that can not be done in Graph. The question is, what is going on at Redmond.

Comment: I haven't come back to this topic for a while, as I have other known problems I am solving for the migration to MS Graph. I have however come across the New-MgUserAuthenticationMethod & Get-MgUserAuthenticationMethod cmdlets, which may lead to a solution, but I've yet to explore it further.

Comment: It is really difficult stuff. Not sure how they made it so complicated - and even if you work it out, it will change in 6months.

Answer (score 0):

You can use New-MgUserAuthenticationPhoneMethod and New-MgUserAuthenticationEmailMethod

For them to work you need to connect to the MS Graph Beta endpoint

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.identity.signins/new-mguserauthenticationphonemethod?view=graph-powershell-beta

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.identity.signins/new-mguserauthenticationemailmethod?view=graph-powershell-beta

Comment: Hmm the phone method seems to require a phone number and I assume the email one requires a personal email? I was looking to simply enforce it so the user was forced to setup on next login. This link appears to show some functions are still not supported: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/authenticationmethods-overview?view=graph-rest-beta&preserve-view=true